# I need to contact google cloud support / unauthorized charges

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have charges on my account for google cloud, I've already canceled my bank card, and an amount still appears, I don't know what google cloud is, and I've never used such a service, I can't access support, because it has to have a project or admin email, and I don't have it, please someone from support answers me, google pay support can't help me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its specific to the users enviorment

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Just follow the [Resolve Cloud Billing issues](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#unrecognized-charges) page that explains the procedure you need to follow.

If you received an unexpected invoice for Google Cloud or Google Maps Platform services, or you see charges for Google services that you do not recognize, submit a Cloud Billing Support ticket through the [Unknown Google Cloud Charge Inquiry](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_unknown_charges) form.

Use can use the form only under the following conditions:

- A form of payment which you own has been charged by Google Cloud
- **You do not own a Google Cloud Account OR the charges are not associated with your Google Cloud Account. (If you own the GCP Billing Account, you should contact Billing Support for faster help)**
- You do not know the owner of the account using your form of payment, OR the account owner is unreachable. (If you know the owner of the account, reach out to them for assistance).

Answer (score 0):

If you have never created a Google Cloud account and do not know the information to login, complete this form and Google will investigate your problem.

[Unknown Google Cloud Charge Inquiry](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_unknown_charges)

If you do have information to login read the follow links:

Google Cloud provides free [billing support](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account). To receive support you will need to login using the Google Accounts identity assigned to the billing account.

Additional information:

[Resolve Cloud Billing Issues](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues)

Google uses Google Payments to process credit cards. Click this [link](https://payments.google.com/) and login. You can then delete/modify the payments account.

If you are sure that this is fraud, complete the fraud forms with your credit card issuer. Your credit card will issue the appropriate credits.